# External Typeface in ExpandableList

Tags: java, android, android-typeface

I am trying to set external typeface in one of my expandable list view. I am trying like below

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    String headerTitleDate = (String) getGroupD(groupPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);

    }

    Typeface bold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "shruti.ttf");
    TextView listTitle = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.tv_listtitle);
    TextView listTitleDate = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
    listTitle.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

    listTitle.setText(headerTitle);

    listTitleDate.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

    listTitleDate.setText(headerTitleDate);

    return convertView;
}
```

**But I am getting getAssets() cannot resolved.** I have tried to use it with Context and without it but not success. Can anyone please suggest me what is wrong with it ?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just make a customised class and just attach it to the TextView in the xml code. I can show the other way round

Comment: plz try this Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(),
                "fshruti.ttf")

Comment: Wondering, why are you using `listTitle.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);` instead of not using `bold`? Anyways your problem is context then `parent.getContext()` may do the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the view's context when doing this, since it is inside an adapter.

You can get the view's context by: `view.getContext()`

Replacing this line:

```
Typeface bold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "shruti.ttf");
```

with this:

```
Typeface bold = Typeface.createFromAsset(convertView.getContext().getAssets(), "shruti.ttf");
```

will fix the error. Hope this helps, let me know if it does.

Comment: can you please explain it with line  Typeface bold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "shruti.ttf"); Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how i do it

**STEP 1:**

I first make a `customizable` font class, for your case you are using `shruti.ttf`

```
    public class Shruti  extends TextView{




    public Champagne(Context context) {
        super(context);

        applyCustomFont(context);
    }

    public Champagne(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        applyCustomFont(context);
    }

    public Champagne(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        applyCustomFont(context);
    }

    private void applyCustomFont(Context context) {
        Typeface customFont = FontCache.getTypeface("shruti.ttf", context);
        setTypeface(customFont);
    }

}
```

**STEP 2:**

Then you also include a `FontCache` class

```
public class FontCache {


    private static HashMap<String, Typeface> fontCache = new HashMap<>();

    public static Typeface getTypeface(String fontname, Context context) {
        Typeface typeface = fontCache.get(fontname);

        if (typeface == null) {
            try {
                typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), fontname);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }

            fontCache.put(fontname, typeface);
        }

        return typeface;
    }
}
```

**STEP 3:**

*Then lastly ,you  attach the customized class on to your `TextView`. in your `xml` item class like this*

```
<company.override.huzykamz.pixsar.customization.Shruti
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/post_desc"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp" />
```

NOTE:

```
company.override.huzykamz.pixsar.customization is just a package name example , but you just put yours.
```

Instead of

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/post_desc"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp" />
```

Hope it works well. ***This is a sure deal solution***